# Changing legend properties for ifelse condition color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've just created a scatter plot by using the code below. Someone got an idea how I can customize the legend title and labels?

```
x <- ggplot(full_data)
x + geom_point(aes(y=r_morning_noon_no_min,x=as.integer(rownames(full_data)),col=ifelse(prediction==1,'green','red'))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean_rm,color="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean_rm2,color="green") +
  ggtitle("Muster von skalierten Haushalten nach Pensionierung separiert") +
  labs(x="Haushalt ID")
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `scale_color_manual` with `name` and `label` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, scale_color_manual was the keyword!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scale_color_manual(name="xxx",values=c("red","green"),labels=c("xxx","xxx"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It was just the missing parameter that was responsible for overwriting the legend parameters. I think everyone can get that information easily out of context by reading the question but thanks for down voting twice.